class template argument deduction when non-type template parameter are used
allowing C++20
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// simple case, CTAD works
template<class T>
struct A {
  A(const T&, int i =0) { cout << "i=" << i << "\n"; }
};


// now I want replace `i` in `A` constructor with an compile time constant - enable e.g. usage of `if constexpr(i==5)`.
// I try to do this via second non-type template parameter.
template<class T, int X>
struct B {
  B(const T&, int i =X) { cout << "X=" << X << "\n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
  long whatever =0;

  A a1{whatever};       // CTAD works
  A a2{whatever, 5};    // CTAD works

  B<long, 2> b1{whatever};    // explicit specified template arguments works
  B b2{whatever, 2};          // cannot deduce template arguments for 'B'

  return 0;
}

It is possible to deduce non-type template parameter, one of my books (C++17 The complete Guide) shows an example:
template<typename T, int SZ>
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass(T(&)[SZ]) {}
};
MyClass mc("hello");  // deduces T as const char and SZ as 6

but I fail miserably ...
And we don't have constexpr function parameter, do we?

It cannot deduce X as there is nothing it could deduce it from. Notice, X is the default value for X, but they don't need to be the same. You cannot deduce X by looking at i.

The trick with the example from the book works because the SZ value comes from a type information (ie. the fixed size of an array) and can be used as a constexpr. However, the parameter i in the constructor of B is, well, a method parameter and can't be used as a constexpr.

So in fact non-type template parameter can't be deduced?

Not in this case.  It needs to be in a context where it is a compile time constant.  You could use a std::integral_constant for example and deduce X from the value of the constant.

What does "allowing C++20" and tagging it C++17 mean?

@Ted Lyngmo, no c++20 tag was offered, or can i freely assign a (custom) tag myself?

@albert there is already a c++20 tag. I changed it for you

Unfortunately, as of C++23, you can't have constexpr function arguments (there is a an indication this might become possible in the future, see P1045R1). For non-type argument deduction to make sense, you need to have a compile-time value from which you can deduce. But since you can't have compile-time (constexpr) function argument, you can't have compile-time value from which you can deduce and thus you can't have non-type argument deduction from non-type function arguments.
However, in the words of Fedor Pikus: "In C++, if you can't do something, but you really really want to, you sort of can". In this case, you need to wrap compile-time value into compile-time type since compile-time types can be used for argument deduction. I would say the simplest way would be to use lambdas. For example:
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct B
{
    B(const T&, auto c)
    requires(std::is_invocable_r_v<int, decltype(c)>) {
        std::cout << "X=" << c() << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    long whatever = 0;
    B b{ whatever, []{ return 2; } };

    return 0;
}

And if you want to go rogue, you can even use macros:
#define CreateB(Arg1, Arg2) B{Arg1, []{ return Arg2; }}

int main() {
    long whatever = 0;
    auto b = CreateB(whatever, 2);

    return 0;
}

Also, depending on the use case, you might need to have that constexpr int within your other type anyways. In that case, you can use that type to deduce constexpr value:
#include <iostream>

template <int X>
struct MyType
{
    // do stuff with X here ...
};

template <template <int> class T, int X>
struct B
{
    // deducing both T and X from function argument
    B(const T<X>&) {
        std::cout << "X=" << X << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    MyType<2> whatever{};
    B b{whatever};

    return 0;
}

But yeah, as of now, this is as close as you can get. It can be annoying, I know. Let`s hope future versions of C++ make it possible. On the other hand, as @cigien has pointed out, this might also never happen.

"there is a good indication this will become possible in C++26" Huh! Is there a proposal

https://github.com/davidstone/isocpp/blob/main/constexpr-parameters.md

constexpr-parameters proposals have been brought up before, but to my understanding there are fundamental problems with making parameters usable in constant expressions, making it unlikely to ever make it into the standard.

I have heard from people relatesd to committee that they are talking about it even for C++26. If so, that should become known very soon. But you might be right, it might never happen. I'll modify that part of the answer to take more conservative stance.

@HolyBlackCat There's also P2781 aka std::constant_wrapper that's being discussed for C++26, and appears to "still be on the table" according to the thread on GitHub

@lobelk, deduce a lambda ... You have to come up with that idea first. And yes, sometimes I go rogue and use macros :)
PS: it was fun to read the linked constexpr-parameters proposal


And we don't have constexpr function parameter, do we?

We don't have constexpr parameter.
But we have types which might have NTTP as: std::integral_constant
So you might do
template<class T, int X>
struct B {
  B(const T& t) : B(t, std::integral_constant<int, X>{}) {}
  B(const T& t, std::integral_constant<int, X>) { // be part of CTAD
     std::cout << "X=" << X << "\n";
  }
};

template <int N>
using ic = std::integral_constant<int, N>;

int main()
{
    B<long, 2> b1{42L}; // explicit specified template arguments works
    B b2{42L, std::integral_constant<int, 2>{}};
    B b3{42L, ic<42>{}};
}

Demo

cool, the std::integral_constant is just the helper vehicle to get the compiler satisfied, it is not even touched inside Bs constructor (presumably completely optimised away). I get something like a partial CTAG. Can live with that as long as T is deduced.

Else, there is still the old way: template <int N, typename T> B<T, N> make_B(const T&); and auto b = make_B<2>(42L);.

oh, I love this old way! Straight and without detours. Packed in a small macro and ready.

using Jarod42s "old way", I ended here
template<class T, int X>
struct B {
  B(const T&) { cout << "X=" << X << "\n"; }
};

template <int N, class T> B<T, N> make_B(const T& t) { return B<T, N>(t); }
#define MAKE_B(obj, val) make_B<val>(obj)

...

B b2 =MAKE_B("Whatever", 42);

